# Differences between for sencha Ext Js with the open source and the commercial licenses

Tags: extjs

I will built an applications using Sencha Ext JS. 
I tried a little application in order to lean it. But I was wonder what are the difference between the GPL and the commercial license?
I noticed that the code is exactly the same, and the way on programming also.
So what are the advantages to buy the commercial license?

Thank you

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about advantages of a license, not programming.

Answer (score 4):

The GPL license is for open source applications.  If you are creating an open source application and are compatible with the GNU General Public License http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html (providing source code etc.) you don't have to buy a commercial license.

If you are releasing an application for commercial purposes and do not plan on sharing the source code... you would have to buy a commercial license.  The advantages?  Staying legal, rewarding Sencha for their great framework and supporting future updates to the framework to name a few!

NOTE: I am not a Sencha representative and/or lawyer.  Contact Sencha http://www.sencha.com/contact/ to find out exactly what is required for your particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

I'M NOT A LAWYER !!!

You can make money if you decide to use the GPL version. However you have to make your application source available moreover any one who is using your app as a library for his application should do too.

If you plan to open source your app then look at this thread: [Which license should I use for my open source project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878280/which-license-should-i-use-for-my-open-source-project)

If not then go with the commercial one. Sencha touch provide a good FAQ regarding licensing: 
https://www.sencha.com/store/licensing-faq/

Good luck with your choose.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help: http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/licensing/
Also i think you require a commercial license if you are going to distribute(sell) your product and wants only you to have the permission to change the source code on the product and customers to only use them, open source license you need if you develop your application for your own purpose and whosever use it do have the permission to make any change in it(source code).

Cheers